# Kotlin method references in place of lambda

Tags: methods, kotlin

Consider the following code, where we take chunks of a list, join them and print to stdout:

```
val l = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
l.chunked(3, { a -> a.joinToString()}).forEach(::println)
```

The code works without a problem. I wanted to change the lambda call (`{ a -> a.joinToString()}`) to the method reference, like this:

```
l.chunked(3, l::joinToString).forEach(::println)
```

The code that uses method reference does not compile and the errors given are:

> Error:(4, 7) Kotlin: Type inference failed: fun 
>   Iterable.chunked(size: Int, transform: (List) -> R): List
>   cannot be applied to receiver: List  arguments:
>   (Int,KFunction6<@ParameterName CharSequence, @ParameterName
>   CharSequence, @ParameterName CharSequence, @ParameterName Int,
>   @ParameterName CharSequence, @ParameterName(name = "transform")
>   ((String) -> CharSequence)?, String>)
>
> Error:(4, 18) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is
>   KFunction6<@ParameterName CharSequence, @ParameterName CharSequence,
>   @ParameterName CharSequence, @ParameterName Int, @ParameterName
>   CharSequence, @ParameterName(name = "transform") ((String) ->
>   CharSequence)?, String> but (List) -> ??? was expected
>
> Error:(4, 21) Kotlin: Type inference failed: fun 
>   Iterable.joinToString(separator: CharSequence = ..., prefix:
>   CharSequence = ..., postfix: CharSequence = ..., limit: Int = ...,
>   truncated: CharSequence = ..., transform: ((T) -> CharSequence)? =
>   ...): String cannot be applied to receiver: List  arguments:
>   ()

Is there a way to compile the code with method references instead of lambda call? I am beginning to learn Kotlin, but suppose that the errors stem from the fact that `joinToString` uses a number of default arguments?

Comment: Seems relevant: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8834  It has a target version of 1.3

Comment: @Michael Seams very relevant! Can you consider changing your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [an open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8834) in the Kotlin issue tracker with the title *"Support function references with default values as other function types"*, which seems to be what's missing for your use-case to work.

The feature currently has a target version of 1.3.

**Update**
The 1.3 Kotlin release does not contain this feature, the target version is updated to 1.4